CKEditor styles issue
According to this documentation in CKEditor https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/getting-started/setup/css.html I should import styles like this 'ckeditor5/ckeditor5.css'. If I importing like in documentation - I have this ESLint error Unable to resolve path to module 'ckeditor5/ckeditor5.css'.
When I change import like this import "ckeditor5/dist/ckeditor5.css"; then I have such error Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ckeditor5/dist/ckeditor5.css' in console
Here is my CKEditor imports
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core": "^43.3.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^6.2.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table": "^43.3.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils": "^43.3.1",

How can I sove this problem?

this is possibly a problem with the bundler, what version of React are you using? can you also create a codesandbox example?
